# Using COUNT aggregate function on sequelize adding unwanted id field

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am trying to do a COUNT on related models using sequelize `6.21.6` get total number of jobs under each category.

My model looks like:

```
models.Sector.hasMany(models.Category, {
   foreignKey: 'sectorId',
   as: 'Categories',
});

models.Category.hasMany(models.Job, {
   foreignKey: 'categoryId',
   as: 'Jobs',
});
```

I am running this query with COUNT:

```
const getSectorsCategories = async () => {
  const sectors = await Sector.findAll({
    attributes: [
      'name'
    ],
    include: [
      {
        model: Category,
        as: 'Categories',
        attributes: ['name', 'sectorId',
          [sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('Categories.Jobs.id')), 'jobCount']
        ],
        include: [
          {
            model: Job,
            as: 'Jobs',
            attributes: ['title', 'categoryId'],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
    group: ['Sector.id', 'Categories.id'],
  },);
  return sectors;
};
```

With the following SQL:

```
Executing (default): 
SELECT 
  "Sector"."id", 
  "Sector"."name", 
  "Categories"."id" AS "Categories.id", 
  "Categories"."name" AS "Categories.name", 
  "Categories"."sectorId" AS "Categories.sectorId", 
  COUNT("Categories->Jobs"."id") AS "Categories.jobCount", 
  "Categories->Jobs"."id" AS "Categories.Jobs.id", 
  "Categories->Jobs"."title" AS "Categories.Jobs.title", 
  "Categories->Jobs"."categoryId" AS "Categories.Jobs.categoryId" 
FROM 
  "Sectors" AS "Sector" 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "Categories" AS "Categories" ON "Sector"."id" = "Categories"."sectorId" 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "Jobs" AS "Categories->Jobs" ON "Categories"."id" = "Categories->Jobs"."categoryId" 
GROUP BY 
  "Sector"."id", 
  "Categories"."id", 
  "Categories->Jobs"."id";
```

You notice this field was added by sequelize automatically: `"Categories->Jobs"."id" AS "Categories.Jobs.id"`

Which now produces this error:

```
"error": "column \"Categories->Jobs.id\" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function"
```

Seems the only way to remove this error is by passing in an empty attributes array to Jobs:

```
include: [
   {
     model: Job,
     as: 'Jobs',
     attributes: [],
   },
]
```

Now the aggregate function `COUNT` works as expected but I don't have any list of job attributes as I wanted.

Is there any workaround for this all-or-nothing approach?

Comment: Grouping by `Categories->Jobs.id` means you will have at most 1 as a count.

Comment: thanks @Anatoly you are right about that, without it I get `"error": "column \"Categories->Jobs.id\" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function"` closer look at the SQL returned, seems like sequelize automatically adds `"Categories->Jobs"."id"` to the SELECT statement :( even when I remove it from the attributes array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using window function.

```
const sectors = await Sector.findAll({
  attributes: [
    'name'
  ],
  include: [
    {
      model: Category,
      as: 'Categories',
      attributes: ['name', 'sectorId',
        [sequelize.literal('COUNT("Categories->Jobs"."id") OVER (PARTITION BY "Sector"."id", "Categories"."id")'), 'jobCount']
      ],
      include: [
        {
          model: Job,
          as: 'Jobs',
          attributes: ['title', 'categoryId'],
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
});
```

Comment: Ah! in the end, I ended up going without sequelize as I was too slow with it, but I will give this a try, thank you!!!

Comment: Yeah, the aggregation with `groupby` is tricky and Sequelize doesn't have support for the Window function. (thus, raw sql with `literal`)