# How to count found elements in Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

**Working query:**

```
const counter = await models.CompanyProductionUnitNonCeased
    .findAndCountAll({
        raw: true,
        distinct: true,
        col: 'company_id',
        limit: 5,
        subQuery: false,
        attributes: ['company_id'],
        include: [{
            attributes: [],
            required: true,
            model: models.ProductionUnitCore,
            as: "production_unit",
            include: [{
                attributes: [],
                required: true,
                model: models.ProductionUnitRented,
                as: 'production_unit_renteds',
                where: { is_current: true },
                include: [{
                    attributes: [],
                    required: true,
                    model: models.AddressAddress,
                    as: 'address',
                    include: [{
                        attributes: [],
                        required: true,
                        model: models.GeograpicalAdministrativeAreas,
                        as: 'geograpical_administrative_areas',
                        include: [{
                            attributes: ['code', 'name'],
                            required: true,
                            model: models.Region,
                            as: 'region_code_region',
                            where: { code: [1081, 1082, 1083] }
                        }],
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        }]
    })
```

**Response for that query:**

```
counter__ {
  count: 462162,
  rows: [
    {
      company_id: 'DK-10000157',
      'production_unit.production_unit_renteds.address.geograpical_administrative_areas.region_code_region.code': 1082,
      'production_unit.production_unit_renteds.address.geograpical_administrative_areas.region_code_region.name': 'Region Midtjylland'
    },
    {
      company_id: 'DK-10000211',
      'production_unit.production_unit_renteds.address.geograpical_administrative_areas.region_code_region.code': 1083,
      'production_unit.production_unit_renteds.address.geograpical_administrative_areas.region_code_region.name': 'Region Syddanmark'
    },
    {
      company_id: 'DK-10000297',
      'production_unit.production_unit_renteds.address.geograpical_administrative_areas.region_code_region.code': 1082,
      'production_unit.production_unit_renteds.address.geograpical_administrative_areas.region_code_region.name': 'Region Midtjylland'
    },
    {
      company_id: 'DK-10000416',
      'production_unit.production_unit_renteds.address.geograpical_administrative_areas.region_code_region.code': 1082,
      'production_unit.production_unit_renteds.address.geograpical_administrative_areas.region_code_region.name': 'Region Midtjylland'
    },
    {
      company_id: 'DK-10000769',
      'production_unit.production_unit_renteds.address.geograpical_administrative_areas.region_code_region.code': 1081,
      'production_unit.production_unit_renteds.address.geograpical_administrative_areas.region_code_region.name': 'Region Nordjylland'
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to count objects with the same *'production_unit.production_unit_renteds.address.geograpical_administrative_areas.region_code_region.code'* field.

**Would be great to have something like that:**

```
{
    count: 462162,
    rows: [
        {
            'production_unit.production_unit_renteds.address.geograpical_administrative_areas.region_code_region.code': 1082,
            total: 3,
        },
        {
            'production_unit.production_unit_renteds.address.geograpical_administrative_areas.region_code_region.code': 1083,
            total: 1
        },
        {
            'production_unit.production_unit_renteds.address.geograpical_administrative_areas.region_code_region.code': 1081,
            total: 1
        }
    ]
}
```

It's not necessary to use **.findAndCountAll()**, we can use just **.findAll()**, because I don't need count field in response

I'm newbie with SQL and seuqelize queries but I'll be grateful for any advice or recommendation.
Thanks everyone for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
const counter = await models.CompanyProductionUnitNonCeased
.findAll({
    raw: true,
    attributes: [
        'production_unit.production_unit_renteds.address.geograpical_administrative_areas.region_code_region.name',
        'production_unit.production_unit_renteds.address.geograpical_administrative_areas.region_code_region.code',
        [sequelize.fn('COUNT', 'production_unit.production_unit_renteds.address.geograpical_administrative_areas.region_code_region.code'), 'total']
    ],
    group: ['production_unit.production_unit_renteds.address.geograpical_administrative_areas.region_code_region.name', 'production_unit.production_unit_renteds.address.geograpical_administrative_areas.region_code_region.code'],
    include: [{
        attributes: [],
        required: true,
        model: models.ProductionUnitCore,
        as: "production_unit",
        include: [{
            attributes: [],
            required: true,
            model: models.ProductionUnitRented,
            as: 'production_unit_renteds',
            where: { is_current: true },
            include: [{
                attributes: [],
                required: true,
                model: models.AddressAddress,
                as: 'address',
                include: [{
                    attributes: [],
                    required: true,
                    model: models.GeograpicalAdministrativeAreas,
                    as: 'geograpical_administrative_areas',
                    include: [{
                        required: true,
                        model: models.Region,
                        as: 'region_code_region',
                        attributes: [],
                        where: {}
                    }],
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }]
})
```

Result:

```
[
  { name: 'Region Sjælland', code: 1085, total: 132696 },
  { name: 'Region Hovedstaden', code: 1084, total: 362711 },
  { name: 'Region Syddanmark', code: 1083, total: 189661 },
  { name: 'Region Midtjylland', code: 1082, total: 224464 },
  { name: 'Region Nordjylland', code: 1081, total: 94023 }
]
```

Can someone help to make only distinct values for CompanyProductionUnitNonCeased by "company_id" value

Comment: You can try window function. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73808849/2956135