# Sequelize how to add distinct and exclude field from group in .findAll()?

Tags: sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have working query:

```
const counter = await models.CompanyProductionUnitNonCeased
    .findAll({
        raw: true,
        attributes: [
            'production_unit.production_unit_renteds.address.geograpical_administrative_areas.region_code_region.name',
            'production_unit.production_unit_renteds.address.geograpical_administrative_areas.region_code_region.code',
            // [sequelize.literal('DISTINCT `company_id`'), 'company_id', 'company_id'],
            [sequelize.fn('COUNT', 'production_unit.production_unit_renteds.address.geograpical_administrative_areas.region_code_region.code'), 'total']
        ],
        group: ['production_unit.production_unit_renteds.address.geograpical_administrative_areas.region_code_region.name', 'production_unit.production_unit_renteds.address.geograpical_administrative_areas.region_code_region.code'],
        include: [{
            attributes: [],
            required: true,
            model: models.ProductionUnitCore,
            as: "production_unit",
            include: [{
                attributes: [],
                required: true,
                model: models.ProductionUnitRented,
                as: 'production_unit_renteds',
                where: { is_current: true },
                include: [{
                    attributes: [],
                    required: true,
                    model: models.AddressAddress,
                    as: 'address',
                    include: [{
                        attributes: [],
                        required: true,
                        model: models.GeograpicalAdministrativeAreas,
                        as: 'geograpical_administrative_areas',
                        include: [{
                            required: true,
                            model: models.Region,
                            as: 'region_code_region',
                            attributes: [],
                            where: {}
                        }],
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        }]
    })
```

The result is:

```
[
  { name: 'Region Sjælland', code: 1085, total: 132696 },
  { name: 'Region Hovedstaden', code: 1084, total: 362711 },
  { name: 'Region Syddanmark', code: 1083, total: 189661 },
  { name: 'Region Midtjylland', code: 1082, total: 224464 },
  { name: 'Region Nordjylland', code: 1081, total: 94023 }
]
```

How can I add distinct by "**company_id**" for model "**CompanyProductionUnitNonCeased**"  key to not add this key into "group", so in total column should be less values (only unique)?

Comment: please try not to duplicate the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to count found elements in Sequelize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74382342/how-to-count-found-elements-in-sequelize)

Comment: this is my own answer for previous question, but I can't set "answered" flag yet. I need count only distinct elements now

Comment: I commented to the original question.  keep the original and close this to help stackoverflow organizing and reducing duplicates.

Comment: @Emma yes, I can close it tomorrow only. It's delay from stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
It just need to add into attributes, where table name is class name of the table :)

```
[sequelize.literal(`count(DISTINCT(CompanyProductionUnitNonCeased.company_id))`), 'count']
```

Here is full solution:

```
const count = await models.CompanyProductionUnitNonCeased
    .findAll({
        raw: true,
        attributes: [
            [sequelize.literal(`count(DISTINCT(CompanyProductionUnitNonCeased.company_id))`), 'count'],
            `production_unit.production_unit_renteds.address.geograpical_administrative_areas.${stringByGroup}.name`,
            `production_unit.production_unit_renteds.address.geograpical_administrative_areas.${stringByGroup}.code`,
        ],
        group: [
            `production_unit.production_unit_renteds.address.geograpical_administrative_areas.${stringByGroup}.name`,
            `production_unit.production_unit_renteds.address.geograpical_administrative_areas.${stringByGroup}.code`],
        where: { ...whereBy },
        include: [{
            attributes: [],
            required: true,
            model: models.ProductionUnitCore,
            as: "production_unit",
            include: [{
                attributes: [],
                required: true,
                model: models.ProductionUnitRented,
                as: 'production_unit_renteds',
                where: { is_current: true },
                include: [{
                    attributes: [],
                    required: true,
                    model: models.AddressAddress,
                    as: 'address',
                    include: [{
                        attributes: [],
                        required: true,
                        model: models.GeograpicalAdministrativeAreas,
                        as: 'geograpical_administrative_areas',
                        include: [{
                            required: true,
                            model: models.Region,
                            as: 'region_code_region',
                            attributes: []
                        }]
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        }]
    })
```